# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined React in asp.net core mvc

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In this case react index.js calling from ASP.NET Core MVC in view in `home.cshtml` in `script type="text/babel"` like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/babel" src="~/reactui/src/index.js"></script>

<div id="root1"></div>
```

index.js in react like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root1'));
root.render(   
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>      
);
```

Getting require is not defined when calling from ASP.NET Core MVC `Index.cshtml` in react index.js.

This project I am add react in ASP.NET Core MVC there are fronted in used react and backend in use C#.

Comment: "import" is not supported in MVC,Please try with with a SPA template